# VLC .NET C# Auto play media only after buffering up to the set postion?

Tags: c#, .net, vlc

I'm trying to use VLC dotnet libraries available from [here.](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) I am able to load the video and show it within a form. However, I am having trouble doing the following:

1. When I set the media of the vlcControl, the control auto plays the media. This is not what I want. I see other examples online where an explicit call to the play method is made to start the media.
2. I need to set the position of the video and buffer to that position before actually playing the media. Is this possible in some way? I can set the position but every time I do it shows the first frame until it buffers up to the set position.

**How can I play media starting at some position only after the media is finished buffering up to the set position?**

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public partial class VlcForm : Form
{
    public VlcForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadMedia(@"C:\Users\jonathan.trowbridge.WVS\Desktop\sampleVideo.mkv");
        SetStartPosition((float)new Random().NextDouble());
        Application.Run(this);
    }

    private void SetStartPosition(float position)
    {
        vlcControl.Position = position;
    }

    private void LoadMedia(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            vlcControl.Media = new PathMedia(path);
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Media not found.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I found I was able to prevent the media from automatically playing once the vlcContext Media property was set by adding the PathMedia to vlcContext Medias and then calling play on the first item in the list with the following code:

```
//vlcControl.Media = new PathMedia(path);
vlcControl.Medias.Add(new PathMedia(path));
vlcControl.Play(vlcControl.Medias[0]);
```

This feels super hacky and still doesn't solve the issue of prebuffering the video before displaying the first frame.

Comment: have you looked at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248(v=vs.110).aspx there is a `seektoposition method`

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to play an mkv file. MKV doesn't seem to be supported by Windows Media player unless I am mistaken. The library seem states that, "All media types supported by Microsoft Windows Media Player 10 are supported in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)."